# Taking string and integers in a single scanf skips the rest of integers after getting the string, why? How to do it only in single scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to take integers and string from a single `scanf`. However, unless I do it with two `scanf`s the code doesn't take the remaining integers. How do I get this single `scanf` function to take everything that I input?

```
struct student {
    int r;
    char a[50];
    int c1, c2, c3;
    float total, per;
} s[100];

main() {
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter total number of students\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter details of student\nRollNo Name c1 c1 c3 marks\n");
        scanf("%d %[^\n]*%s %d %d %d", &s[i].r, s[i].a, &s[i].c1, &s[i].c2, &s[i].c3);
       // scanf("%d %d %d", &s[i].c1, &s[i].c2, &s[i].c3);  this works 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %s %d %d %d\n", s[i].r, s[i].a, s[i].c1, s[i].c2, s[i].c3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `" %[^\n]*%s"` supposed to do?

Comment: You need to enable compiler warnings: `prog.c:14:23: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’`

Comment: Your code is not valid C89/90 (`//` comments, missing `return` statement in `main`), but it's not valid C99 either (missing return type in `main()` declaration). Also, you're missing `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @melpomene %[^n]*%s allows spaces within the string entered. It takes input untill \n occurs

Comment: include.... was a copying mistake

Comment: am using codeblocks btw

Comment: No, that's not what `" %[^\n]*%s"` does. The first `" "` will skip over any whitespace (including newlines). Then `%[^\n]` will read a string of one or more non-newline characters (which can include spaces; this part is correct). Then `*` will attempt to read a `*` character. This attempt will always fail (because `%[^\n]` just consumed all non-newline characters) and it is at this point that `scanf` returns an error (which your code doesn't realize because it ignores scanf's return value). If `*` hadn't failed, then `%s` would skip over all whitespace again and read a word of input.

Comment: I don't care what IDE you're using; you need to enable compiler warnings (and pay attention to them).

Comment: @melpomene thanks a lot for that explanation!

Comment: @melpomene what does 0-9 specify in the answer by chqrlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format to read a string of characters different from newline is `%[^\n]`, with an optional but highly recommended width prefix for the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array. The trailing `*%s` is meaningless. 
Note however that this `scanf` conversion specifier will accept the mark numbers as part of the name:

`scanf` should stop reading the name when it finds a digit. This will allow the user to give the input on a single line per student, which he/she might do anyway given the prompt.

The format for that is `%[^0-9\n]` and to prevent undefined behavior if the user types more than 49 characters for the name, specify this limit with `%49[^0-9\n]`.

Using `scanf()` to parse input is still brittle: recovering from invalid input is tedious.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    int r;
    char a[50];
    int c1, c2, c3;
    float total, per;
} s[100];

int main() {
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter total number of students\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n > 100)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n;) {
        printf("Enter details of student\nRollNo Name c1 c1 c3 marks\n");
        if (scanf("%d %49[^0-9\n] %d %d %d",
                  &s[i].r, s[i].a, &s[i].c1, &s[i].c2, &s[i].c3) == 5) {
            i++;
        } else {
            int c;
            fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
            /* consume the rest of the input line */
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "unexpected end of file\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %s %d %d %d\n", s[i].r, s[i].a, s[i].c1, s[i].c2, s[i].c3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @xing: I was typing it as you were commenting :)

Comment: That will go subtly wrong if one of the c1's is negative.

Comment: @chqrlie thnx that worked after editing that fprintf typo(was it? It gave me error)... But I didn't get what %49.. did to make the code work....

Comment: @DeepakPawade: the `49` between the `%` and the `[` specifies the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array before the null terminator. It is a protection against invalid input that would otherwise cause undefined behavior. The same is recommended for `%s` too.

Comment: @chqrlie so basically my code was taking invalid inputs somehow due to "%[^\n]*%s" coz i didn't set up some limits and what does 0-9 specify?

Comment: @DeepakPawade No, your format string was wrong. Removing `*%s` fixed the visible behavior. Adding `49` made it safe against users typing overlong names.

Comment: @melpomene: sharp eye! I'm having a slow day.